# How can I separate the chosen data from jquery chosen plugin for storing data into a database?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am trying to use jquery chosen plugin. I have to process the chosen id into a database.
So, I need to separate those id selected by jquery chosen plugin.
[https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen]

I want to separate those id and store into a database one by one using ajax. 
It will be better if you provide me an array into here.
So that after selecting the tags , when the user will click the submit button, after then in jquery I will process that array. Then I will retrieve that array values using a loop.

How can I separate those data chosen by jquery chose plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is leverage the `.change()` function, then inside of this function you can get reference to the selected option.

```
$('.field').chosen().change(function(){
    //You can now use normalized jQuery functions against `$(this)`
});
```

Comment: It will be better if your provide me an array into here.So that after selecting the tags , when the user will click the submit button, after then in jquery I will process that array.

Then I will retrieve that array values using a loop.
Please, update your code and keep an array into your comment,so that I can retrieve it.